# Cron job string settings to fire 4 times a day in between 5-10

Tags: php, cron, cronjob

`* 5-10 * * *` will fire the script between the said timings but how will I control the count?

BTW the count and the timings can be anything, means it will be dynamic and not static. Just put up a static numbers for better understanding.

Answer (score 2):

One problem with your script is that it will run every minute (because of the first "*").

Since you have 6 hours, it's pretty hard to run the cron only 4 times.

One solution could be:

```
0 6,7,8,9 * * * /path/command
```

Answer (score 0):

Y'all don't get cron. It does not "dynamic" - it runs when you ask it to run, without variance.

If you want 4 times between 5 & 10, just pick 4 times, and write 4 lines. There are precisely no points for "getting it done in 1 line" and few, if any for compacting it.

i.e.:

```
17 5 * * * (command)
37 6 * * * (command)
17 8 * * * (command)
37 9 * * * (command)
```

Or you might really want more like:

```
1 5 * * * (command)
37 6 * * * (command)
17 8 * * * (command)
59 9 * * * (command)
```

Or if you love compacting (for which there are still few, if any points awarded):

```
17 5,8 * * * (command)
37 6,9 * * * (command)
```

Unless you actually meant 5 to 10 **PM** (in which case) :

```
17 17,20 * * * (command)
37 18,21 * * * (command)
```

If you have some need (I'll play dubious) for actual dynamic-like behavior here, you will be writing a script to dynamically create a crontab that non-dynamically does what you want done until the next time you change the crontab.